# Identifying slow-running tests

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

In ruby's test/unit, the software indicates how long it takes for the tests to run, and the series of passes, errors and fails act like a pseudo-progress bar.

Apart from using code profiling tools or running tests individually, is there an easy way of telling which test methods are fast and which ones are slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to do this in a large test suite, I override Test::Unit::TestCase setup and teardown. It doesn't give precise measurements, but it can help assess relative speed.

```
module Test
  module Unit
    def setup
      @start_time = Time.now
    end

    def teardown
      puts "#{@method_name}: #{Time.now - @start_time}s"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Sarah's answer, I would prefer another solution:

Setup like Sarah wrote, but the Teardown should add the test name and the execution time in a list.
So you can evaluate this list, for sorting or whatever. I don't know Ruby, so I don't know if it would work.

Here is some Java code for JUnit to explain my thoughts...

```
public class ExecutionTimeTest {

  public static ArrayList<Double> executionTimes;

  public double start;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void initializeList() {
    executionTimes = new ArrayList<Double>();
  }

  @AfterClass
  public static void printExecutionTimes() {
    int i = 1;
    for (Double time : executionTimes) {
      System.out.println("Test " + (i++) + ": " + time);
    }
  }

  @Before
  public void startExecutionTime() {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

  @After
  public void calculateExecutionTime() {
    executionTimes.add(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. In Ruby you'd probably want to do that in the TestSuite class. If you added it to TestCase there would be one execution_times array for each test class, rather than one for the suite.

Comment: That's the difference between BeforeClass and Before. BeforeClass will be executed ONE time, Before will be executed for every test case.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the test-unit gem, running the tests in verbose mode will give you information on how long each test took:

```
ruby test/test_unit.rb --verbose
Loaded suite test/test_unit
Started
ChaserTestCase: 
  test_handle_funny_characters_in_class_method_names:   .: (0.000645)
  test_handle_funny_characters_in_instance_method_names:.: (0.000523)
  test_modify_and_unmodify_class_method:                .: (0.000534)
...
Finished in 0.019894 seconds.
```

MiniTest will [also](http://lists.zenspider.com/pipermail/ruby/2010-October/005343.html) have benchmarking.